# colors stripe using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have TV box with Android 4.4.4, ExoPlayer 1.5.2 and I have problem with Stream from m3u file.
All is working good just some channels with high resolution got colors stripe.
Color offset and stripe height is depended on video resolution.

[image]

[image]

I have used other applications for example vlc,mxPlayer at the same device and it's working perfectly.
and I have added these Urls to the demo of exoPlayer you can find it under name MyTest. and this is the download link of the demo:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/zanobclq4nb3u4r/ExoPlayer-release-v1.zip

with the smart phones it's working good, but just in the android boxes, the problem when you stream a file with resolution 1280/720 and up the problem appears 
the android version of the device 4.4.4